# Check user for more than three login attempts using different browsers

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net-2010

I want to check in my application that if the user has entered the password wrongly from different browsers for three times using VB.NET? If it is for same browser and the user enters the value continuously I can make it by declaring the variable to take the count.. But when it comes for different browsers and for later session how it will work..?? Can anyone suggest me a idea..!!

Comment: you have to save into database for that to work out

Comment: do u mean the count value to be stored in the database??

Comment: yes else you cannot find users trying from different browsers or using Private browsing

Comment: yep.. that is a gud idea.. thank u..

Comment: please mark as answer if was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the login details and attempt in the database.
As saving into database will help you find users trying from different browsers and also from incognito/private login sessions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most common practice would be to add a field in your user table and simply increment that on every wrong login; and reset it to 0 on succesful login.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned only about wrong password attempt and if you have stored user credentials in the database table then introducing a new column to store wrong password attempt would be the better option and reset the value based on your requirement, say forgot password reset or admin unlock